# getting output as json instead of array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to match the input with the array of names that I have created. Here is the code for it:

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import process
>>> names = ["Adam Gilchrist","Adam Barbar","Adam lobiof","Jaffer Wilson","Janet Wilson","Jane Cold"]
>>> process.extract('adamgilchrist',names)
[('Adam Gilchrist', 84), ('Adam lobiof', 50), ('Jane Cold', 50), ('Adam Barbar', 40), ('Janet Wilson', 30)]
```

What I am getting is just an array of the name and confidence.

I want to display the output as json something like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "Adam Gilchrist",
      "confidence": 84
    },
    {
      "name": "Adam lobiof",
      "confidence": 50
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Cold",
      "confidence": 50
    },
    {
      "name": "Adam Barbar",
      "confidence": 40
    },
    {
      "name": "Janet Wilson",
      "confidence": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using python 2.7 on windows 10 sysytem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking in combination with a list comprehension for this:

```
...
result = process.extract('adamgilchrist',names)
result = [{"name": name, "confidence": confidence} for name, confidence in result]
```

which results in

```
[{'confidence': 84, 'name': 'Adam Gilchrist'}, {'confidence': 50, 'name': 'Adam lobiof'}, {'confidence': 50, 'name': 'Jane Cold'}, {'confidence': 40, 'name': 'Adam Barbar'}, {'confidence': 30, 'name': 'Janet Wilson'}]
```

You can reach your final result (if necessary) with minor adjustments:

```
{'result': results}
```

which in turn is then

```
{'result': [
    {'confidence': 84, 'name': 'Adam Gilchrist'},
    {'confidence': 50, 'name': 'Adam lobiof'}, 
    {'confidence': 50, 'name': 'Jane Cold'}, 
    {'confidence': 40, 'name': 'Adam Barbar'}, 
    {'confidence': 30, 'name': 'Janet Wilson'}]
}
```